# Force include node_modules in package?

Tags: npm

I want to `npm publish` my `dist` dir that looks like this:

```
dist
├── README.md
├── node_modules
│   └── clap
│       └── dist
│           └── es
│               ├── index.js
│               └── index.js.map
├── package.json
...
    └── utils
        ├── memory-stream.js
        ├── memory-stream.js.map
        ├── mysql-users.js
        ├── mysql-users.js.map
        ├── sql.js
        ├── sql.js.map
        ├── utils.js
        └── utils.js.map
```

Notice how there's a `node_modules` dir in there. I want to publish that along with everything else.

The files in there *are* compiled, but they're part of a local package not distributed on npm, so I do want it bundled.

My code references it like this:

```
var index = require('../node_modules/clap/dist/es/index.js');
```

So it should work perfectly fine.

The problem is that it looks like `npm publish` has it hardcoded to ignore directories called `node_modules`. Is there any way to override that behaviour?

Comment: AFAIK npm does not provide a setting to enable `node_modules` to be published via `npm publish` - the `node_modules` dir is always excluded. Perhaps another approach to try is: **1)** Use [`npm pack`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-pack) to create the tarball (.tgz). **2)** In _package.json_ define a [postpack](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/scripts#life-cycle-scripts) script that triggers a node.js script which adds `node_modules` to the resultant tarball (using e.g. [node-tar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tar)). **3)** Then `npm publish /path/to/updated/tarball.tgz`