# "Unresolved dependencies" even when using rollup-plugin-node-externals & @rollup/plugin-node-resolve

Tags: node.js, rollupjs

My rollup config looks like this:

```
import {babel, RollupBabelInputPluginOptions} from '@rollup/plugin-babel'
import {nodeResolve} from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve'
import nodeExternals from 'rollup-plugin-node-externals'
import json from '@rollup/plugin-json'
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs'
import findUp from 'find-up'
import {readFileSync} from 'fs'
import packagePlugin from '@mpen/rollup-plugin-package'
import cleanPlugin from '@mpen/rollup-plugin-clean'
import runPlugin from '@mpen/rollup-plugin-run'
import execPlugin, {RollupPluginExecutableOptions} from '@mpen/rollup-plugin-executable'
// import renameNodeModules from 'rollup-plugin-rename-node-modules'
import type {RollupOptions, WatcherOptions} from 'rollup'

// see also: https://github.com/rollup/rollup-starter-app

interface RollupPresetTsappOptions {
    tsconfig?: string
    babelOptions?: RollupBabelInputPluginOptions
    watch?: WatcherOptions
    nodeOptions?: RollupPluginExecutableOptions
}

type Truthy<T> = T extends false | '' | 0 | null | undefined ? never : T;  // https://stackoverflow.com/a/58110124/65387

function truthy<T>(value: T): value is Truthy<T> {
    return Boolean(value);
}

export default function rollupPresetTsapp(opts: RollupPresetTsappOptions = {}): RollupOptions {
    const tsconfigFile = findUp.sync(opts.tsconfig ?? 'tsconfig.json')
    if(!tsconfigFile) throw new Error('tsconfig.json file not found')
    const tsconfig = JSON.parse(readFileSync(tsconfigFile, 'utf8'))
    const extensions = ['.ts', '.mjs', '.js', '.json', '.node'];
    const isWatch = process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH === 'true'

    return {
        input: tsconfig.files,
        plugins: [
            !isWatch && cleanPlugin(),
            nodeExternals({
                builtins: true,
                deps: isWatch,
                devDeps: isWatch,
                peerDeps: true,
                optDeps: true,
            }),
            nodeResolve({
                extensions,
                preferBuiltins: true,
            }),
            commonjs({
                include: 'node_modules/**',
            }),
            json({preferConst: true}),
            babel({
                exclude: 'node_modules/**',
                extensions,
                comments: false,
                babelHelpers: 'bundled',  // https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/babel#babelhelpers
                root: `${__dirname}/..`,
                // babelrcRoots: ['.', __dirname],  // https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options#babelrcroots
                ...opts.babelOptions,
            }),
            execPlugin({
                maxOldSpaceSize: 4*1024,
                enableSourceMaps: true,
                ...opts.nodeOptions,
            }),
            // renameNodeModules('external'),
            !isWatch && packagePlugin(),
            isWatch && runPlugin(),
        ].filter(truthy),
        watch: {
            buildDelay: 200,
            clearScreen: false,
            ...opts.watch,
        },
        preserveSymlinks: true,  // https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rollup/plugin-commonjs#usage-with-symlinks
        preserveModules: false,  // outputs multiple files; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66219812/force-include-node-modules-in-package  https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/3684
        output: {
            // banner: `#!/usr/bin/env -S node --max-old-space-size=${opts.memory ?? 8192} --enable-source-maps`,
            dir: 'dist',
            format: 'cjs',
            sourcemap: true,
            exports: 'named',
        },
    }
}
```

However, when compiling my project I get:

```
(!) Unresolved dependencies
https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#warning-treating-module-as-external-dependency
parse5 (imported by parse5?commonjs-external)
mariadb (imported by mariadb?commonjs-external)
highlight.js (imported by highlight.js?commonjs-external)
parse5-htmlparser2-tree-adapter (imported by parse5-htmlparser2-tree-adapter?commonjs-external)
bl (imported by bl?commonjs-external)
log-symbols (imported by log-symbols?commonjs-external)
cli-cursor (imported by cli-cursor?commonjs-external)
cli-spinners (imported by cli-spinners?commonjs-external)
strip-ansi (imported by strip-ansi?commonjs-external)
wcwidth (imported by wcwidth?commonjs-external)
is-interactive (imported by is-interactive?commonjs-external)
fs-constants (imported by fs-constants?commonjs-external)
inherits (imported by inherits?commonjs-external)
readable-stream (imported by readable-stream?commonjs-external)
end-of-stream (imported by end-of-stream?commonjs-external)
supports-color (imported by supports-color?commonjs-external)
ansi-styles (imported by ansi-styles?commonjs-external)
emoji-regex (imported by emoji-regex?commonjs-external)
is-fullwidth-code-point (imported by is-fullwidth-code-point?commonjs-external)
```

I don't want any of these to be treated as external, but they're not being compiled in even though I have `nodeResolve`. Why not?

Looks like none of them are direct dependencies of my project, but indirect (dependencies of my dependencies).

Comment: I suspect it has to do with this pnpm's directory structure: https://pnpm.js.org/blog/2020/05/27/flat-node-modules-is-not-the-only-way

Comment: I can partly fix it by telling `pnpm` to install a flat `node_modules` like `npm`; `pnpm i --shamefully-hoist`